# Curious behavior while formatting dates

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

I'm getting a string representation of a date from a json that looks like the following:

```
let dateString = "2016-12-31T00:10:00+01:00"
```

In order to model it as a Date object I'm using a date formatter like so:

```
let dateForm = DateFormatter()
dateForm.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
dateForm.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
dateForm.timeZone = TimeZone.current
```

When I turn it into a Date, my Playground output is correct:

```
let date = dateForm.date(from: dateString)
```

=> Output: "Dec 31, 2016, 12:10 AM"

But if I try to print this exact same object (date) I get the following output:

```
print(date!)
```

=> Output: "2016-12-30 23:10:00 +0000\n"

My question is: How can I be sure that I'm dealing with the correct date (by correct I mean with my local time zone (GMT+01)) ?

Comment: You are getting the correct date your time is changed because your string date is `UTC + 1:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print the date output `2016-12-30 23:10:00 +0000` and your GMT is `+00:00`
but when you get  the string from date it will return string as per your given format And your `Locale` (fr_FR) output `2016-12-31T00:10:00+01:00` and your GMT is `+01:00` 
if you want to date from string then

**date output = your string date - (your GMT)**

In your case

```
2016-12-30 23:10:00 = 2016-12-31 00:10:00 - (+01:00)
```